# Trying to access an array from ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I'm trying to Sort an array from my ArrayList:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    al.insert(0, 4);
    al.insert(1, 3);
    al.insert(2, 2);
    al.insert(3, 1);

    SelectionSortWrappers<Integer> ss = new SelectionSortWrappers<Integer>();
    ss.sort(al.elements);
    ss.show(al.elements);
```

But when I try to access `al.elements`, I'm getting:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;
```

Here is my SelectionSort Class:

```
public class SelectionSortWrappers<T>{

    public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(T[] array){
        int index;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length;i++){
            index = i;
            for(int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++){
                if (array[j].compareTo(array[index]) < 0){
                     index = j;
                }
            }

            T smaller = array[index];
            array[index] = array[i];
            array[i] = smaller;
        }

    }

    public void show(T[] array){
        for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

My ArrayList, i had to create, because is for my university project, i cannot use the Java one.

```
package Lists;

public class ArrayList<T> implements List<T> {

private static int MAX_SIZE = 10;   
private static final int NOT_FOUND = -1;            


public T[] elements;

protected int size; 

public ArrayList() {
    size = 0;
    elements = (T[]) new Object[MAX_SIZE]; 
}
public T[] getArray(){
    return elements;
}

public int find(T v) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(v == elements[i]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return NOT_FOUND;
}


public T elementAt(int pos)  {
    if(pos >= 0 && pos < size) {
       return elements[pos];
    }
    throw new InvalidArgumentException();
}


public void insert(int pos, T v) {
    if (size == MAX_SIZE){
        elements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, size * 2);
        MAX_SIZE = size * 2;
    }

    if(pos == size) {
        elements[size] = v; 
    }
    else { 
        for(int i = size; i > pos; i--) {
            elements[i] = elements[i-1];
        }
        elements[pos] = v;
    }
    size++;

}


public void remove(int pos) {
    if(pos >= 0 && pos < size) {
        for(int i = pos; i < size-1; i++) {
            elements[i] = elements[i+1];
        }
        size--;
    }
    else {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    }
}


public int size() {
    return size; 
}

public void show(boolean reverse) {
    if (!reverse){
        for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
            System.out.print(elements[i] + " ");
        }
    } else {
        for(int i=size; i >= 0; i--){
            System.out.print(elements[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Where is the problem? My `elements` field is public.

Comment: Is your `ArrayList` something you created, or the built-in Java `ArrayList`?

Comment: we need your `ArrayList` implementation, especially its `.insert()` method

Comment: You really shouldn't give your classes the same name as a core Java class.  You will cause no end of confusion that way.

Comment: I created this ArrayList, is part of my university project, and had to name it ArrayList

Comment: That means that none of us can possibly know what it does, so you need to [edit] your question to include the relevant parts of your implementation.  At the very least, you need to show us how you are declaring the `elements` field you're having a problem with.

Comment: Ok, i put my ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into the predictable erasure-versus-arrays problem caused by doing `(T[]) new Object[MAX_SIZE]`.  You'll get a warning on that line -- that warning is warning you about exactly this problem.

Your `ArrayList` class is *pretending* an `Object[]` is a `T[]`, but it really isn't -- the actual referenced array is still an `Object[]`. When you pull it out with `al.elements`, it tries to actually cast it to an `Integer[]` and fails.

You will have to do something ugly to deal with this -- like what the built-in `java.util.Collection.toArray(T[])` has to do, for example.  Alternately, you could write your sorting method to access your `ArrayList` directly instead of trying to work on its underlying array.